# Create a duplicate of a string but reversed in C

Tags: c, loops, reverse, c-strings

I am trying to create a duplicate of a string but reversed.
I am able to strcpy each char and print them individually but I get nothing when I print the entire duplicate string.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char    str[101] = "Lieur a Rueil";
    char    temp[101];
    int     i;
    int     j;

    i = 0;
    j = strlen(str);

    while (str[j] - 1)
    {
        strcpy(&temp[i], &str[j]);
        printf("%c", temp[i]);
        j--;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
    return (0);
}
```

output:

```
lieuR a rueiL
temp:
```

Comment: Why are you using `strcpy` instead of copying a single character?

Comment: What do you think `str[j] - 1` actually does? Maybe you meant `str[j - 1]` instead? Though `i < j` wouuld make more sense. And `strcpy()` is not how you swap characters of a string. In any case, why not just use an existing function like `strrev()` or equivalent instead?

Comment: No, you *cannot* `strcpy()` individual characters.  The `strcpy()` function does not do that.  But you can use ordinary assignment: `temp[i] = str[j]`.  Don't forget to add a string terminator at the end of the copy.

Comment: Indeed, strcpy is a mistake, my bad ^^

Comment: (a) terminate the new string with '\0', (b) use simple `temp[x] = str[y]` to copy chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This while loop

```
while (str[j] - 1)
{
    strcpy(&temp[i], &str[j]);
    printf("%c", temp[i]);
    j--;
    i++;
}
```

does not make a sense. The condition of the loop can invoke undefined behavior
due to accessing memory beyond the array. The same problem exists with the call of `strcpy`.

The main logic of the program can be implemented simpler. For example

```
size_t i = 0;

for ( size_t j = strlen( str ); j-- != 0; i++ )
{
    temp[i] = str[j];
}

temp[i] = '\0';

printf("\ntemp: %s\n", temp);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char str[] = "Lieur a Rueil";
    char temp[sizeof( str )];
    
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( size_t j = strlen( str ); j-- != 0; i++ )
    {
        temp[i] = str[j];
    }

    temp[i] = '\0';

    printf("\ntemp: %s\n", temp);   
}
```

The program output is

```
temp: lieuR a rueiL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    char    str[101] = "Lieur a Rueil";
    char    temp[101];
    size_t  sz = strlen(str);
 
    for(size_t i=0;i<sz; ++i)
    {
        temp[sz-i-1] = str[i];
    }
    temp[sz]=0;
 
    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
    return (0);
}
```

### Output:

```
temp: lieuR a rueiL
```

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes to original code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char    str[101] = "Lieur a Rueil";
    char    temp[101];
    int     i;
    int     j;

    i = 0;
    j = strlen(str);

    temp[j] = '\0';
    while (j)
    {        
       temp[j -1] = str[i];
        printf("%c", temp[j]);
        j--;
        i++;
     }
     printf("\n");
     printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
     return (0);
}
```